# compare two arrays and filter out which are taken and which available

Tags: php, laravel

I am struggling with the following

I have a table called **plates**

```
 {
        "id": 1,
        "plate_container_id": 1,
        "plate_container_slot": 1,
        "deleted_at": null,
        "created_at": "2015-10-21 18:42:26",
        "updated_at": "2015-10-21 18:57:27"
}
```

And I have table called **platecontainers**

```
{
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Prof. Carroll Smitham PhD",
        "number_of_slots": 7,
        "description": "Asperiores reiciendis",
        "created_at": "2015-10-21 18:42:25",
        "updated_at": "2015-10-21 18:42:25"
    }
```

What I want is -- When he user selects a `platecontainer` the `number_of_slots` are compared with the one in `plates` table (which is `plate_container_slot`) and checks which `slots` are already occupied (or taken) by any other `plates`. If the `slot` is taken, the user gets to see those as grayed out, otherwise they are available to use.

Now I am using Angularjs and Laravel 5. Would someone please tell me what is the best way to achieve this? And how to do it? I am little confused about it.